# Distance calculated using CLLocationManager is Always More

Tags: ios, swift

i have tested most of the big Distance calculating Apps on App Store and all of them have the same issue that their calculated mileage does not match with the odometer of the car .

here is my code and if it is incorrect . is there any way to get the 100% accurate distance ?

```
       if lastLocation != nil
         {
           if locations.last?.horizontalAccuracy <= 10 && locations.last?.speed > 0 && locations.last?.horizontalAccuracy > 0
             {    
                 let currentLocation = locations.last! as CLLocation;                       

                    if currentLocation != lastLocation
                    {
                        traveledDistance = currentLocation.distance(from: lastLocation)
                    }
             }
          }
       else
         {
         if  locations.last?.horizontalAccuracy <= 10
           {
             lastLocation = locations.last! as CLLocation
           }
         }
```

Comment: traveledDistance += currentLocation.distance(from: lastLocation)*

Comment: Over any appreciable distance the errors accumulated from GPS inaccuracy and the fact that you are adding a series of line segments are going to add up. There will also be a degree of inaccuracy in the odometer based on things like tyre pressure and tyre wear

Comment: So it means its not possible to get the accurate distance ? What about the companies charge their customers based on traveled distance like uber ? Are they charging more without letting the customers know .

Comment: I wouldn't expect the error to be very large.  Even if it was a mile, the extra cost would be around $1-$2.  Of course the error could work in the passenger's favour as the distance measured could be less.  The passenger also has the option of a traditional taxi where the meter is linked to the driveshaft and is regularly calibrated, so may be more accurate but their tariffs are higher, so even with the error, Uber is cheaper or more reliable or has nicer cars or whatever motivates the passenger to chose them.

Comment: Also, as I suggested it may be the odometer that is inaccurate.  The distance measured by GPS might be the more accurate figure; you don't know

Comment: Ive been working on this mileage issue for a long time and to test Uber i took 5 journey during different times in different vehicles and the average i was charged was 3% more ( not less )  i know its not a lot of money for an individual but for uber being a big company it could be big loss in compensation and reputation. Car odometers are 99% accurate apparently

Comment: Check this app and see if this matches with your Odometer

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/taxifaremeter/id1061329817?mt=8

Comment: Ok. I tried that. My odometer read 15.0km. The app reported 14.95km. This sounds ok since in Australia car speedometers must read "high" - https://www.racq.com.au/cars-and-driving/safety-on-the-road/driving-safely/speedo-accuracy so I would expect the car to record a slightly longer distance than the GPS(but 50m over 15000m is pretty close). I live in the country so there are no tall buildings to interfere with the GPS signal

Comment: Thank you so much for testing . This is my app and i wanted to prove my point that the methods being used to calculate the distance are wrong . I am not using any conventional methods to calculate the distance . Its my own algorithm